# QT can't display 4k image, can only display 1/6 of 4k image

Tags: c++, qt

I use QT 6.4 version, after receiving PCIE data in the memory, after that display, but display 3840x2160 image data Image only the top 1/6 have image, but no image below, when I receive 1080p data can be displayed normally.

```
newWindow::newWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::newWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pcie_c2h_event0.isplay = false;
    connect(&pcie_c2h_event0, SIGNAL(sig_inform_disp()), this, SLOT(disp_slot()));
    connect(&pcie_c2h_event0, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(slotThreadFinish()));
    m_Qimage = new QImage(c2h_align_mem_tmp,3840，2160,QImage::Format_RGB32);
   if(!pcie_c2h_event0.isRunning()) pcie_c2h_event0.start();
}

newWindow::~newWindow()
{
    pcie_c2h_event0.isplay = false;
    while (pcie_c2h_event0.isRunning());
    pcie_close();
    delete ui;
}
void newWindow::disp_slot()
{
    QPixmap m_Qpixmap;
    if(pcie_c2h_event0.isplay == false)
        return;
    ui->label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    read_pack((char*)c2h_align_mem_tmp,3840*2160*4,0);

    m_Qpixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(*m_Qimage,Qt::AutoColor);
 
    ui->label->setPixmap(m_Qpixmap);
}
```

[error image here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK00T.jpg

I tried to modify the resolution of ui and qimage, but it still didn't change the image I was hoping to finish

Comment: [Don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question to copy-paste all and any text *as text*.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).